# How to upgrade a Chocolatey package ONLY if it's installed (never install)?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I want to upgrade a specific package but only if its not installed. I run an update script that keeps all my pc's up2date. `cup all` and `choco upgrade all` work well for exactly this purpose, but does not handle apps that install locally under user appdata, like f.lux. So I do this to traverse the different users and install those apps that do user space install:

```
$orgUserProfile=$Env:USERPROFILE
$orgLocalAppData=$Env:LOCALAPPDATA
$Env:USERPROFILE="C:\users\Alex"
$Env:LOCALAPPDATA="${Env:USERPROFILE}\AppData\Local"
# Installed to c:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\SourceTree 
choco upgrade sourcetree
choco upgrade f.lux
$Env:USERPROFILE="C:\users\Lisa"
$Env:LOCALAPPDATA="${Env:USERPROFILE}\AppData\Local"
# I'm not sure updates will work for lisa, not sure I want to force it, it seems choco is not multi-user
choco upgrade f.lux
$Env:USERPROFILE=$orgUserProfile
$Env:LOCALAPPDATA=$orgLocalAppData

cup all
```

However on some of my PC's I don't have sourcetree, f.lux installed already and I don't want my upgrade script to install them.

Is there a simple way to make chocolatey only upgrade if its already installed? So I don't have to parse the list manually

PS:

[Here's like the opposite question](https://superuser.com/questions/1277968/how-can-i-upgrade-a-chocolatey-package-if-its-already-installed-and-install-it/1277976#1277976)

[Here's the choco upgrade documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-upgrade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not exist currently, but follow https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1646 - if that releases in the planned version, that will be part of v0.10.12.

Comment: Ah, great info, thank you for the link to the issue, I didn't think to check there first.